# Errors in React Cmd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, cmd, setup-project

that's happened when I tried to setup react as w3schools said and react documentation
I tried to solve those problems and all my trying doesn't work.
the problems are

```
err code ElifeCycle
err errno 1
 my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
err Exit status 1
Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script
a complete log of this run can be found :
this is not an npm problem
```

there are the additional logging output above
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXA0b.jpg)

Comment: Can you paste a full log ?

Comment: what's the my-app start script, can you post that? (or show how you set it up)

Comment: just create a new project, make sure you installed `create-react-app` corretly (uninstall and reinstall). make sure you didn't install `react-scripts` package manually (whether globally or locally), ...

Comment: I tried to reinstalled and same errors appeared

Comment: the full log inside the image